# Problemas de errores al crea una aplicación con tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estoy aprendiendo Python y al seguir unos ejercicios de como crear una aplicación utilizando tkinter y sqlite3, se me presentan algunas dificultades, más bien errores, que espero ustedes puedan ayudarme. Se que es muy básico para ustedes, pero estoy en eso ahora. Desde ya les agradezco su tiempo y paciencia.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
# from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st

import sqlite3

class Product:
        
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Products Application')
        
# Creating a Frame Container
frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Register a New Product')
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspam = 3, pady = 20)

# Name Input
Label(frame, text = 'Name: ')
Label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
self.name = tk.Entry(frame)
self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

y el error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 16, in <module>
    frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Register a New Product')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

y también me marca como errores:
Label
self.name
todas las veces que aparece.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, ten en cuenta que en la linea `frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspam = 3, pady = 20)` el parametro `columnspam` en realidad es `columnspan`.
Y que para que funcione:

```
Label(frame, text = 'Name: ')
Label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

Tienes que "guardarlo" en un objeto:

```
label = tk.Label(window, text = 'Name: ')
label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

Luego, el problema que estas teniendo es que estas definiendo los componentes de la ventana fuera de la clase, o sea, todo esto:

```py
# Creating a Frame Container
frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Register a New Product')
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspam = 3, pady = 20)

# Name Input
Label(frame, text = 'Name: ')
Label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
self.name = tk.Entry(frame)
self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

lo que podes hacer es poner todo dentro de un método nuevo llamado, por ejemplo, constructor y que tome como parámetro self:

```py
def constructor(self):
    # Creating a Frame Container
    frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Register a New Product')
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)        

    # Name Input
    label = tk.Label(window, text = 'Name: ')
    label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    
    self.name = tk.Entry(frame)
    self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

y en  **init**() agregas la llamada a constructor:

```py
def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Products Application')
        self.constructor()
```

y el programa final seria algo como:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
# from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st

import sqlite3

class Product:
        
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Products Application')
        self.constructor()

    def constructor(self):
        # Creating a Frame Container
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Register a New Product')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)        
    
        # Name Input
        label = tk.Label(window, text = 'Name: ')
        label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        self.name = tk.Entry(frame)
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: muy informativo, lo entendí sin problemas, lo voy a probar y te comento. Desde ya muchísimas gracias Mr.Barbo

Comment: no hay problema, para eso estamos. No soy muy experto en esto, si me equivoqué en algo te pido disculpas, solo hablo desde lo que aprendí programando en tkinter.

Comment: no tenes porque pedir disculpas, yo se menos que vos, además, lo importante es la intención y aprender. te comento que ahora me tira este error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 40, in <module>
    application = Product(window)
  File "index.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.constructor()
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'constructor'```

Comment: observa si esta bien identado todo, te advierte que constructor no esta en Product.

Comment: Lo voy a investigar, pude solucionar que aparezca la ventana, pero no me aparece la parte del ingreso de datos, desde ya gracias.